# Jenkins maven related errors

Tags: maven, jenkins

Hi I have a problem with my jenkins job. What I'm trying to achieve is a CI pipeline hovewer I'm getting some maven related erros with which I have no idea how to deal with. Could you please tell me what seems to be the problem here?

[image]

Comment: You probably misspelled the Maven goal that you are trying to call (the plugin name lacks `:`, maybe you wrote `.` instead).

Comment: What is the maven command used?

Comment: @JFMeier that was exactly what was going on. Thank you very much!